# Scala distributed middleware

Tags: scala, middleware

Is there any distributed middleware, like JXTA or JMS, for Scala?
I'm looking for a middleware that provides discovery, name service, service publications, availability verification, groups and so on, for Scala language.

Comment: Of course, any Java library or framework providing these can be used with Scala. It may just not be a natural fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka stack has many features , if you want AMQP reference then http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/amqp.html

Comment: AMPQ provides greats features, but not all i'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this to help you use JMS in Scala, should you so wish

https://github.com/fancellu/jmsScala

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "for Scala".  Since it runs within the JVM, with very good interoperability with Java, you can just use whatever Java-based facilities float your boat.  In some cases there may be Scala "skins" available, but it doesn't matter a lot.  For instance, [here's an article on using ActiveMQ from Scala](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/jms-how-to-do-synchronous-messaging-with-activemq-in-scala/), with no Scala skin.

Comment: Hello,I mean use the functional languages facilities for concurrency and scalability, without java-based(object oriented) limitations. Thanks, i will analyze the indicated article.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go further than Viral and say that [Akka](http://akka.io) is the answer you're looking for. It doesn't provide all the features you mention (or at least takes a different approach to some of them) but it's a very powerful middleware suite that distributes well and is getting a lot of use and attention.